# How do I get the details of an Error 500 for an Azure Web App?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC 6 site that has been deployed as an Azure Web App. I have enabled all tracing / diagnostic options in Visual Studio using Server Explorer. I am trying to do remote debugging, but I am only seeing an Error 500 on my browser, and not finding any information (or triggering an error breakpoint) on where exactly the error occurred.

I can't find any error trace on the file logs that I get from Azure.

How should I troubleshoot Error 500's in an Azure Web App?

Adding "CustomErrors": {"Mode": "Off"} to config.json didn't work.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using when you try to do remote debugging?  Also, you may want to consider adding Application Insights to your web app.

Comment: I am using VS 2015 RC. It says that it is not supported.

Comment: I just found from the detailed errors XML that it is caused by  MapRequestHandler. No other details were provided.

Comment: Yeah, that's just going to tell you where in the asp.net pipeline the error occurred. To get details from your application, you need some diagnostics logging in your application. Or, remote debug it but as you say it's not supported in VS2015 yet.  Application Insights is really useful but I've not tried it with VS2015. One thing you can do without making any change to your code is install the Diagnostics as a service extension to your web app. Reproduce the error and then run the extension & look at the memory dump analysis. It will show you the call-stack and the exception msg. from your app

Comment: The error is because my Authentication AppId and AppSecret needs to be installed separately on the server. Apparently just copying the config.json file doesn't work. I don't know how to do set this up yet. I have posted a new question about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438382/setting-appid-and-appsecret-configuration-in-azure-websites

Comment: @JonasArcangel how were you able to determine that it was your AppId and AppSecret that was causing the problem?  I am having the same issue "500 errors with zero visibility". I would love to know how find out what is causing it.

Comment: @RickRainey You said "One thing you can do without making any change to your code is install the Diagnostics as a service extension to your web app." - How do I install the "Diagnostics" as a service extension? Is that in the Azure Portal somewhere?

Comment: @jessegavin In the preview portal (portal.azure.com), from the Web App blade go to Settings -> Extensions.  From there, add the Diagnostics as a Service extension.

Comment: @jessegavin I found out the hard way. In the absence of any troubleshooting information, I had to make a copy of my solution, and removed / commented things out one by one. It was a pain and I'm sorry I can't provide an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MVC 6 you need to add a web.config file to the wwwroot folder with the following:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That will add the markup to the deployed web.config file, and give you detailed errors. See http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/diagnostics.html#http-500-errors-on-azure for more details.

Comment: Hi, Rick. I'm not sure if there's something else I need to set. It works locally (I'm able to see the stack trace on the Error 500 page). However, on Azure, it doesn't have the trace. I confirm that the Config file has also been deployed.

Comment: It didn't work. I have that web.config file, but I still only get Error 500 without any details.

Comment: How did you confirm you have the correct markup in the correct web.config? You don't need custom errors on IIS Express to get detailed error messages. Use Kudu to confirm the correct web.config is on azure. Sounds like you have invalid XML in your web.config, in that case it won't use your customErrors settings. There are multiple failure vectors.

Comment: It seems that the web.config works only in later stages of the pipeline, like when invoking actions? It doesn't appear when it is during initialization or when there's a problem with the handlers (or when the IOC is confused with multiple DLLs.)

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT So given what Jonas is saying...what is the fix?  How can I find out what the error is?

Comment: Modifying the web.config as above does not work - in addition, there is no doc behind the posted link

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to enable LOG files on Azure.

In MVC Core you do that by setting stdoutLogsEnabled=true in web.config ->  ->

Then you go to Azure App Service console, Click on Diagnostics Logs under MONITORING Category.

There you have FTP link, where you have your LOG files stored.

Open it and you will see a detailed error. Dont forget to stop your App Service Server before you try to open LOG file, otherwise it won't be accessible.

Hope that helps you.