# Azure Web Application Raising Internal Server Error when talking to API Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, internal-server-error

I have an solution that consists of a web gui front end and a web api backend.  Both use Azure AD for auth with the former passing a token to the latter.

This all works fine on both a localhost and an OnPrem server, but when I push the release to Azure, I get a 500 Internal Server error when the GUI attempts to utilise the API.

At the moment, I am unable to obtain any further error detail.

I know this is a little vague, but I am pretty new to the whole Azure platform and am unsure how to diagnose the issue further.

Any assistance or pointers that people can give would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> I know this is a little vague, but I am pretty new to the whole Azure platform and am unsure how to diagnose the issue further.

Per my understanding, you could follow the steps below to troubleshoot this issue:

For .NET web application, you could add `customErrors` flag in the Web.config file and set the value to `On` or `RemoteOnly` to see the detailed error message. Also, you could enable [diagnostics logging for web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to retrieve more details about the error message. Or you could just leverage [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) for a simple way to locate the specific issue. For more details, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio) about troubleshooting azure web apps.

For .NET Core web application, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419618/how-do-i-get-the-details-of-an-error-500-for-an-azure-web-app). Additionally, for php, you could refer to [nfo About PHP Fatal Error and Error Log on Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/15/info-about-php-fatal-error-and-error-log-on-azure-website/) and [Change the built-in PHP configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations) to troubleshoot this issue.